# How to test if the google search app indexing is working or not?

Tags: android, android-app-indexing, firebase-app-indexing, google-app-indexing

I have verified the domain name on search console and I have added intent filters in my app. I can open the app using the adb command

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "http://www.mywebsite.com/path" com.my.package.debug
```

and it is opening the proper screen. My doubt is that how does google search will map the URLs? Also, as of now, I can't see the links being redirected to my app on Google search. Is it because the app is not updated on the play store?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: @AndroidEnthusiast no I haven't